# Scraping yellowpages hrefs with python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I recently posted asking to scrape data from yellowpages and @alecxe helped out tons by showing me some new ways to pull the data but I'm stuck yet again and would like to scrape the data for each link in yellowpages so I can get the yellowpages page which has more data on them. I want to add a variable called "url" and grab the href of the business, not the actual businesses website but the yellowpages page of the business. I've tried all kinds of things but nothing seems to work. The href is under "class=business-name".

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('cities_louisiana.csv','r') as cities:
    lines = cities.read().splitlines()
cities.close()

for city in lines:
    print(city)
url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=businesses&geo_location_terms="baton%rouge+LA&page="+str(count)

for city in lines:
    for x in range (0, 50):
        print("http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=businesses&geo_location_terms=baton%rouge+LA&page="+str(x))
        page = requests.get("http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=businesses&geo_location_terms=baton%rouge+LA&page="+str(x))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
        for result in soup.select(".search-results .result"):
            try:
                name = result.select_one(".business-name").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            except:
                pass
            try:
                streetAddress = result.select_one(".street-address").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            except:
                pass
            try:
                city = result.select_one(".locality").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
                city = city.replace(",", "")
                state = "LA"
                zip = result.select_one('span[itemprop$="postalCode"]').get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            except:
                pass

            try:
                telephone = result.select_one(".phones").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            except:
                telephone = "No Telephone"
            try:
                categories = result.select_one(".categories").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            except:
                categories = "No Categories"
            completeData = name, streetAddress, city, state, zip, telephone, categories
            print(completeData)
            with open("yellowpages_businesses_louisiana.csv", "a", newline="") as write:
                wrt = csv.writer(write)
                wrt.writerow(completeData)
                write.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple things you should implement:

- extract the business links from the `href` attribute of elements with `business-name` class - in `BeautifulSoup` this can be done by "treating" an element like a dictionary
- make links absolute using `urljoin()`
- make requests to business page while maintaining a web-scraping session
- parse the business pages with `BeautifulSoup` as well and extract the desired information
- add a time delay to avoid hitting the site too often

Complete working example that prints out business names from the search result page and a business description from the business profile pages:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin  

import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=businesses&geo_location_terms=baton%rouge+LA&page=1"


with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'}

    page = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    for result in soup.select(".search-results .result"):
        business_name_element = result.select_one(".business-name")
        name = business_name_element.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")

        link = urljoin(page.url, business_name_element["href"])

        # extract additional business information
        business_page = session.get(link)
        business_soup = BeautifulSoup(business_page.text, "html.parser")
        description = business_soup.select_one("dd.description").text

        print(name, description)

        time.sleep(1)  # time delay to not hit the site too often
```

Comment: just amazing! I still so new to python and programming in general. Your solution works amazing although I made a slight change by adding just the`business_name_element = result.select_one(".business-name")` and the `link = urljoin(page.url, business_name_element["href"])`. As I read over your code I reverse engineer it so it makes sense. Thanks for your support!

Comment: i'm running your code as it is but im getting error in the description part.